# Visual Studio Addin - 1. How to Add a context menu? 2. How to get caret position

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm writing a (very) simple Visual Studio addin.  Two things that would make it work nicer are:

1. A context menu.
2. Knowing the caret position in the current document (so I can inject text at that position).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a context menu to your addin, you create a CommandBarPopup from:

```
_applicationObject.CommandBars["Code Window"]
```

You can view a sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/addingmenuitems.aspx).

The second part of your question is a little simpler, the current "selection" (or insertion point) is handled by:

```
(TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection
```

"_applicationObject" is an instance the DTE Application object created by the add-in project wizard.